# Can I use all 4 sides of a polarizing beamsplitter cube as inputs?

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, reflection, geometric-optics, polarization

The polarizing beamsplitter cube on the following diagram splits non-polarized light in the input *a* into 2 orthogonal polarizations: p-polarized light is transmitted into the output *c* while s-polarized light is reflected into the output *b*.

Can I use other sides as inputs? For example, can I combine p-polarized light in the input *d* and s-polarized light in the input *a* into the output *b*?

[image: diagram]

Comment: Generally that would work but not be optimal because of the glue/cement. You want the orientation shown.

Comment: @JonCuster If it isn't optimal, what are the typical negative consequences?

Comment: The polarization ratios won’t be as good. You want that nice glass-coating interface doing the polarization separation, not the glue-coating-glass interface(s).